# Iterator String Array not grabbing all elements

Tags: java, android, arrays, iterator

This logic makes sense to me, and I can not wrap my head around why it would only be printing out the last element, but for some reason this code runs fine except for each element in my spinner it says Course: 5 and "ShortCourseDesc6" for each one. It should be incrementing each time.

```
public void setListData()
{       
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

        List<String> imageURLArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        imageURLArray.add("ShortCourseDesc1");
        imageURLArray.add("ShortCourseDesc2");
        imageURLArray.add("ShortCourseDesc3");
        imageURLArray.add("ShortCourseDesc4");
        imageURLArray.add("ShortCourseDesc5");
        imageURLArray.add("ShortCourseDesc6");

        Iterator<String> iter = imageURLArray.iterator();

        final SpinnerModel sched = new SpinnerModel();

          /******* Firstly take data in model object ******/
        for(int z = 0; iter.hasNext(); z++) 
        {
            sched.setCourseName("Course: " + z);
            sched.setImage("image" + z);
            sched.setCourseShortDesc(iter.next());
        }

        /******** Take Model Object in ArrayList **********/
        CustomListViewValuesArr.add(sched);
    }

  }
```

Comment: As per ur current code ShortCourseDesc1 to ShortCourseDesc6 will be going to print 6 times.I dnt see only 6 will be print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have more spinners. :) because you updates only sched SpinnerModel object. And you print it after iterating over all elements so it you got ShortCourseDesc6 and 5.
try changing your code to:

```
public class SpinnerData{
    private String courseName;
    private String image;
    private String courseShortDesc;
   //getters and setters...

}

 List<SpinnerData> schedList = new ArrayList<SpinnerData>();

          /******* Firstly take data in model object ******/
        for(int z = 0; iter.hasNext(); z++) 
        {
            SpinnerDatasched= new SpinnerData();
            sched.setCourseName("Course: " + z+1);
            sched.setImage("image" + z+1);
            sched.setCourseShortDesc(iter.next());
            schedList.add(sched);
        }
SpinnerListModel spinnerListModel = new SpinnerListModel(schedList);
```

or simply... if my suggestion is wrong try another

```
  /******* Firstly take data in model object ******/
for(int z = 0; iter.hasNext(); z++) 
{
    SpinnerModel sched = new SpinnerModel();
    sched.setCourseName("Course: " + z+1);
    sched.setImage("image" + z+1);
    sched.setCourseShortDesc(iter.next());
    CustomListViewValuesArr.add(sched);
}
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, how do I add more spinners to a spinner? And that's exactly what prints "Course: 5 and ShortCourseDesc6" 6 times

Comment: I have put two versions check which suits you.

Comment: it doesnt like "SpinnerListModel" did you mean "SpinnerModel" or "List<SpinnerModel>" ?

Comment: Spinner list model is a class from java swing. SpinnerModel is an Abstract class so you can not initialize it. Because in java abstract class can't be created using 'new'. Look on first my listing, there I implemented you model class SpinnerData.

Answer (score 1):

You update the same spinner over and over again, and as I understand correctly, `SpinnerModel` is an interface, so how do you instantiate it? I think the solution is to use a `SpinnerListModel` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerListModel.html):

```
SpinnerModel model = new SpinnerListModel(Arrays.asList("Hello", "This", "Is", "A", "Spinner", "List", "Model"));
```